# Conditional elementwise sum in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have found a solution to cumsum the previous numbers if they are negative:

```
def func(x):
    for i, value in enumerate(x):
        if i == len(x)-1:
            break
        if value < 0:
            x[i+1] += value
    x = x.clip(min=0)
    return x

data = np.array([-3, 4, -2, -2, 6])
print(func(data))
>>>> [0 1 0 0 2]
```

Is there a vectorized numpy solution? This is a very small data sample, but it will become quite large and is 2D such as:

```
data = np.array([[-3, 4, -2, -2, 6],[1, -2, -3, 7, 1]])
```

And I would like to apply it rowwise.

Comment: Is the last number in `[0 1 0 0 2]` correct? Shouldn't it be `[0 1 0 0 3]`?

Comment: It is correct: -2-2+6=2

Comment: Ok, but +1-2-2+6=3. So it is not a cumulative sum. Or do you only want the cumulative sum of consecutive negative numbers?

Comment: You are right, it is the cumulative sum of consecutive negative numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadly speaking, vectorization relies on the fact that many elements of the array can be processed independently of all other elements, and can then make use of operations that can be applied to all elements of an array at once. However because your calculation relies on results from previous iterations, it needs to run linearly through the data.

Therefore it is probably not possible to fully vectorize your problem. But since the calculation of each row is independent of each other row, there is some room left for vectorization: Here is a solution that vectorizes across all columns and just loops over all rows

```
def func(x):
    x = x.copy()
    for i in range(len(x) - 1):
        mask = x[i, ...] < 0
        x[i+1, mask, ...] += x[i, mask, ...]

    x = x.clip(min=0)
    return x

data = np.array([[-3, 4, -2, -2, 6],[1, -2, -3, 7, 1]])
func(data.T)
# array([[0, 1],
#        [1, 0],
#        [0, 0],
#        [0, 2],
#        [2, 1]])
```

I am aware that instead of columns you want to treat each row individually, however I chose to swap the two as in general iterating like this over the first dimension of an array is more efficient than iterating over the last dimension:

```
data = numpy.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10000, 10000))
%timeit colwise_func(data)  # 1.08 s ± 35.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit rowwise_func(data)  # 2.31 s ± 65.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. Can you briefly explain why it is not possible to fully vectorize?

Comment: And, unfortunately it gives an error when applying to a 1-D array np.array([-3, 4, -2, -2, 6]): `IndexError: in the future, 0-d boolean arrays will be interpreted as a valid boolean index`. Is there any solution to make the function more general?

Comment: I am not seeing any error and am getting the result `array([0, 1, 0, 0, 2])` using NumPy 1.14.0.

Comment: I have added some remarks about vectorization and why this problem probably can't be vectorized.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a binarized array of your data. Once you defined your threshold, binarize it with `np.where`:

```py
data = np.array([-3, 4, -2, -2, 6])
binarized = np.where(data>0, 1, 0)
# array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
```

The `np.where` function returns an array the same size as `data`, where any value above your threshold (here equal to 0) will be set to 1, and all other will be set to 0.

Then simply multiply its cumulative sum with itself. It will sum all values, and set zeros where there are no valid sums.

```py
np.cumsum(binarized)*binarized
# array([0, 1, 0, 0, 2])
```

For 2-dimensional arrays use a similar approach, but give the axis you want to sum on. In your case you want it along the rows, so set it to `axis=1`:

```py
data = np.array([[-3, 4, -2, -2, 6],[1, -2, -3, 7, 1]])
binarized = np.where(data>0, 1, 0)
np.cumsum(binarized, axis=1)*binarized
# array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 2],
#        [1, 0, 0, 2, 3]])
```

Your function can merely be:

```py
def func(data, t=0, ax=1):
    b = np.where(data>t, 1, 0)
    return np.cumsum(b, axis=ax)*b
```

There parameter `t` sets the threshold, while the parameter `ax` is the axis to sum over. Giving a `None` will sum all values of the array.